# How To Rename Files that Being Downloading using Javascript and PHP Header?

Tags: javascript, php

just like my title how can I do that thing?
I tried to code like below (in file view_report.php)

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=report_loader.txt');
?>
<div id="reportTable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($reports->result() as $rows): ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php $rows->no; ?></th>
                <th><?php $rows->name; ?></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Generate Excel" id="exportExcel" />
</div>
<script>
    $("#exportExcel").click(function (e) {
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#reportTable').html());
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 </script>
```

**EDIT**
That is my entire code. I already tried it. I referred some questions in this Site, but I don't fine clean solution for me. I actually have tried to use `Content-Disposition: inline` and `Content-Disposition: attachment`. But still not working. The browser (I tried on Chrome and Firefox), it returns random file name, not the file name I want. Can anyone help me to find this solution?

Comment: There's a [possible fail in Chrome](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/05/http-headers-content-type-and-content.html) that requires the content-type to be set to, say, `application/octet-stream` for the filename to be taken from the `content-disposition` and not guessed from the URL.

Comment: still not work if I use `application/octet-stream` or `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no "inline" for Content-Disposition.

Can you try:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=report_loader.txt');
```

---

Update:
Sry, there IS inline for Content-Disposition. But you should use that if you want the browser to display the content, not download it. Therefore it will probably ignore the filename attribute.

Source:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt

---

Update 2:

Try this:

```
var blob = new Blob([$('#reportTable').html()], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "table.html");
```

This should save the HTML from #reportTable as table.html

Note: If you want to create an Excel file, you will need more than just the html source.

Comment: thanks for answering. I have tried both `inline` and `attachment` for that. But still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$file_name='abc.txt';
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .$file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<a href="/your/file/destination" download="file_name_for_user">Download Your Downloading Thingy</a>
```

Please, check this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

It states:

> download
>
> This attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource so that when the user clicks on the link they will be prompted to save it as a local file. If the attribute has a value, the value will be used as the pre-filled file name in the Save prompt that opens when the user clicks on the link (the user can change the name before actually saving the file of course). There are no restrictions on allowed values (though / and \ will be converted to underscores, preventing specific path hints), but you should consider that most file systems have limitations with regard to what punctuation is supported in file names, and browsers are likely to adjust file names accordingly.